# CSS trouble with my header in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am working on the following site: http://tcsdesignreno.com/nvvolunteers/.

It looks great in Firefox and Chrome but when I go to the home page in Internet explorer it drops the navigation menu down along with the social media icons on the left side (see the image below). Can anyone help me with finding the error in my css code so it will look correct across all browsers.

I am testing in IE 10 but have the same problems in later version.

I think the problem is coming from the top-margin in the social media area css but I can't figure out how to position it right above the nav bar without using this code.

POSSIBLE HTML CODE

```
<div class="social-media-home">
                <a title="Follow us on Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/NevadaVolunteers" target="_blank">
                    <img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-924" title="Follow us on Facebook" alt="Facebook" src="http://tcsdesignreno.com/nvvolunteers/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/facebook.png" width="32" height="32" />
                </a>
                <a title="Check us out on Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/nvvolunteers" target="_blank">
                    <img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-922" title="Follow us on Twitter" alt="Twitter" src="http://tcsdesignreno.com/nvvolunteers/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/twitter.png" width="32" height="32" />
                </a>
                <a title="Pin us on Pinterest" href="http://pinterest.com/nvvolunteers/" target="_blank">
                    <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-921" title="Pin us on Pinterest" alt="Pinterest" src="http://tcsdesignreno.com/nvvolunteers/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/pinterest.png" width="32" height="32" />
                </a>
                <a title="See us on Instagram" href="http://instagram.com/nvvolunteers#" target="_blank">
                    <img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-923" title="See us on Instagram" alt="Instagram" src="http://tcsdesignreno.com/nvvolunteers/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/instagram_64x64.png" width="32" height="32" />
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-926" style="display: none;" title="Add us on Google +" alt="Google Plus" src="http://tcsdesignreno.com/nvvolunteers/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/GooglePlus.png" width="32" height="32" />
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-925" style="display: none;" title="Find us on Linked In" alt="LinkedIn" src="http://tcsdesignreno.com/nvvolunteers/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/linkedin.png" width="32" height="32" />
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-923" style="display: none;" title="Watch us on YouTube" alt="YouTube" src="http://tcsdesignreno.com/nvvolunteers/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/youtube.png" width="32" height="32" />
                </a>                
            </div>

            <div id="home-nav-container">
            <div class="resizer"><span id="font-resizer-ticker"></span></div>

            <div id="home-nav"><?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => '5' )); ?></div>
            </div>
```

POSSIBLE CSS CODE

```
.social-media-home {
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    margin: 4.2rem 0.5rem 0 0;
    clear:right;
}

.social-media-home img {
    margin: 1rem 5px 0 0!important;
}

#home-nav-container {
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
 clear: right;
}
#home-nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 0.8rem 1.0714rem 0 0;
}

#home-nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#home-nav li a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#home-nav li:not(:last-child):after
{
    content: ' |';
}

.resizer {
    /*clear:right;*/
    float:right; 
    padding: 0.8rem 1.0714rem 0 0;
}
```

SCREEN SHOT

[image: IE Nav Problems]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

float left on .main-navigation and
float left on the title link inside the header hgroup -> I'd recommend putting this inside a div

Below is the site working in IE

[image: working in IE]